# How To Compile with Framework 3.5 instead of 4.5 (VS2012)

Tags: vb.net, frameworks

I have recently written two small apps in Visual Studio 2012 (VB). I compiled them using Framework 4.5. These have been tested on the end user's PC's and the feedback was to try and get the Apps Compiled using Framework 3.5 as this is already installed on the computers.The computers are using Windows 7.

My questions are these:

1. Is it possible to force a compile to use 3.5 instead of 4.5?
2. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to target the 3.5 framework when you compile.

Go to PROJECT-> Properties (You can also right-click on the project in the solution viewer and select Properties).

Select .NET Framework 35. in the Target Framework dropdown.

The project will be closed and reopened automatically by Visual Studio (you will be asked to confirm this change).

Note that if you have anything specific to .NET 4.0/4.5 that is **NOT** present in the 3.5 framework you will have to make the necessary changes.

**EDIT**

A picture is worth a thousand words:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This is the first time I have written in VB.Net (previous experience is VB3, 4, 5 & 6) all last touched 5 years ago. A lot has changed since!